# Trying to make a delete option for entries to a blog on django/heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have a project (learning_log) where you can add topics and in those topics you can add entries. I have an edit entries option but I want to add a delete entries option too. I did the following, but I am still getting an internal error when I try to load it on heroku. :

1. Made the url...

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #...

    #Page for deleting an entry
    path('delete_entry/',views.delete_entry,name='delete_entry'),

    ]
```

2. wrote the view

> views.py

```
def delete_entry(request, entry_id):
  """Delete an existing entry"""
  entry = get_object_or_404(Entry,id=entry_id) #getting the entry object the user wants to delete
  topic=entry.topic
  check_project_owner() #This is a custom function (I know it works) Making sure the person who wants to delete it is the owner
  entry.delete() #Delete the entry
  context = {'entry':entry} #I don't even think we need to pass this but I just want to be safe and pass something
  return render(request, 'learning_logs/delete_entry.html', context)
```

3. made the html template

> delete_entry.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<a>Your quote has been deleted. Please click a link at the top of the 
page to return.</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

4. linked to it from my "edit entries page"

> edit_entries.html

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>Edit Entry in '<i><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</i></a>':</h2>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}" method='post' class='form'>
    {% csrf_token %} <!-- Used to prevent hacking -->
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    {% buttons %}
      <!-- creating a submit button -->
      <button name="submit" class='btn btn-primary'>Edit Entry</button> 
    {% endbuttons %}

  </form>

  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:delete_entry' entry.id %}">Delete Entry</a>


{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your URL patterns no argument passed to view. but your view take an extra argument called `entry_id`. update your url to solve this problem like this:

```
url_patterns = [
    ...
    #Page for deleting an entry
    path('delete_entry/<int: entry_id >/',views.delete_entry,name='delete_entry'),
]
```

Comment: Hi vorujack, I am still receiving an error even after your change. I believe it has to do with my edit_entry.html code, because I get my server error when I click on edit entry in my server. Any ideas?